Are there any numerically-plausible perfect binary code parameters besides (90,2)?
(Formerly on Math StackExchange here, without much progress.)
In order for a perfect binary code on $n$ symbols to correct $k$ errors, we need the sum
$${n\choose 0}+{n\choose 1}+\ldots+{n\choose k}$$
to be a power of two, since the number of codewords is $2^n$ divided by that sum. If one looks in Pascal's triangle for such sums, one finds:

$k=n$, corresponding to a code with a single keyword (trivial)
$k=0$, corresponding to a code with all $2^n$ codewords that corrects no errors (trivial)
$k=\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ when $n$ is odd, corresponding to two codewords (trivial)
$n=2^m-1, k=1$, corresponding to a Hamming code
$n=23, k=3$, corresponding to the perfect Golay code.

All of the above correspond to real error-correcting codes, and in fact the above is a complete list of perfect binary codes (see e.g. the assertion in section 2 here). But there are numerical coincidences in Pascal's triangle that don't lead to a perfect binary code, such as the fact that
$${90\choose 0}+{90\choose 1}+{90\choose 2} = 4096 = 2^{12}$$
I'm curious whether there are any other such numerical coincidences in Pascal's triangle. It seems that there aren't - I've checked the first 1,000,000 rows - but I don't know how I'd prove this.
